# Blow up and morphism of locally free sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, blowup

I would like to know if what I say below makes sense.

Let $X$, $Y$ be smooth projective varieties, $Y \subset X$ and $\pi: \widetilde{X} \longrightarrow X$ the blowing-up of $X$ along $Y$.

We know that $$\pi: \widetilde{X}\setminus E \longrightarrow X\setminus Y \tag{$*$} $$  is an isomorphism. Let $F$ and $L$ be locally free sheaves on $\widetilde{X}$ with $\text{rank(F)} = 3$ and $L$ a line bundle.

In $\widetilde{X}\setminus E$ is it possible to define a surjective morphism $\psi : F \longrightarrow L$?

If so, is it immediate that this morphism is surjective due to the fact $(*)$?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $X=\Bbb P^3$ and $Y=\{[1:0:0:0]\}$ with $F'=\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^3}^3$ and $L'=\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^3}(1)$, and let $f':F'\to L'$ be given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{pmatrix}$. Then this map is surjective on $X\setminus Y$, and by letting $\pi^*F'=F$ and $\pi^*L'=L$, we get the desired counterexample.

Comment: If $Y = \biggl \{ [z] \in  \mathbb{P}^{3};  z_{0} = z_{1} = 0 \biggr \}$ is the reasoning analogous? thank you very much.

Comment: Yes - take the same $F',L'$ and adjust the map to $\begin{pmatrix} z_0 & z_1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$, for instance.

Comment: Under what conditions will such a surjective morphism exist?

Comment: The failure of the morphism to be surjective is computed by the cokernel. You're looking for conditions which imply that it's zero, while knowing that it's zero on some open set. I don't see anything off the top of my head which would do this (though maybe I'm forgetting something obvious). If you have a specific situation in mind, this could be an instance of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) in which case you should follow the advice at the link.

Comment: You're looking for conditions which imply that it's zero, while knowing that it's zero on some open set. Making $U = \widetilde{X}\setminus E$, can I say then that this morphism is generically surjective? Thank you.

Comment: If $U$ is dense, this is exactly the definition of generically surjective.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104114/discussion-between-allain-jf-and-kreiser).